# Expanded Dropdown Menu Hover Margin in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, user-interface, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I would like to slightly expand the hover region for a CSS dropdown menu, so that the mouse position can extend for 10px off of the dropdown list without collapsing it.  I have tried to implement this with an invisible "wrapper" div, which works great in FireFox and Chrome and Safari, but does not work in IE (currently testing in IE10).

IE does recognize hovering over the invisible "wrapper" div, but only if no other content is behind the div.  (If I change the wrapper background to a color, then the hover is recognized regardless.)

Does anyone have a solution for consistent hovering behavior in IE, or a simple CSS alternative for an invisible hover margin?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mac_dempsey/vzxa96rw/).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul class="menu-item">
<li>
<a href="" class="menu-link">Item 1</a>
<div class="menu-item-list-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-item-list">
        <a href="">Link 1</a><br />
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu-item">
...
</ul>
...
</div>

.menu
{
    float:right; margin:20px;
}
.menu-item {
    float:right; position:relative; list-style:none;
    margin:5px; padding:0px;
    z-index:2;
}
.menu-link {
    padding:5px; border:solid 1px blue;
}
.menu-item li
{
    z-index:2;
}
.menu-item-list-wrapper {
    position:absolute; display:none;
    top:23px; right:-10px;
    height:120px; width:220px; padding:0px;
    z-index:2;
    border:dashed 1px #BBB;  /* For Demonstration */
}
.menu-item-list{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; right:10px;
    height:80px; width:180px; padding:10px; 
    background:white; border:solid 1px blue;
    z-index:2;
}
.menu-item li:hover .menu-item-list-wrapper
{
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend just not doing it.